# Slide a div off screen (with margin: 0px auto)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontally centered div `#box1` that has `margin: 5px auto` that has to slide to the left and off the screen, while `#box2` slides into the screen from the right, when the button `.class` is clicked on. I've seen how its done for absolutely positioned divs, now how do you do it if its not?

**HTML Structure**

```
<div class="button"><a href="#">Slide</a> </div>

<div id="container">

    <div id="box1" class="box">Box #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Box #2</div>

</div>
```

**Failed attempt**

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $("#box1").css('margin-left', 0);
    $("#box1").css('margin-right', 0);
    $("#box1").animate({
            left: '150%',
        }, 'slow' );

});
```

Comment: @DarkMantis Updated the original post with my attempt. I dont want to have to use jQuery to position a absolutely-positioned div in the center, then animate the `left` css property to achieve the slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the effect you're looking for: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UWLsB/)**.

jQuery:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $("#box1").css('margin-left', 0);
    $("#box1").css('margin-right', 0);
    $("#box1").animate({ left: '-500px' }, 'slow');
    $("#box2").animate({ left: '0px' }, 'slow');
});​
```

CSS:

```
#box1, #box2 {
    margin: 5px auto;   
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position:relative;
}
#box2 {
   left:500px;   
}
#container {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

​
HTML:

```
<div class="button"><a href="#">Slide</a> </div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box">Box #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Box #2</div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to slide out a dive you could use jQuery UI hide methods

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $("#box1").hide('slide', {
        direction: "left"
    }, 2000);
});
```

and you can do the same to slide in

```
$("#box2").show('slide', {
    direction: "left"
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $("#box1").animate({
        marginLeft: '-150%',
    }, 'slow' );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to, it wouldn't be difficult to absolutely position the element in the same spot it was before animation.

```
var elm = $("#box1");
var position = elm.position();
var cssObj = {
  'position' : 'absolute',
  'top' : position .top,
  'left' : position.left
}
elm.css(cssObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```
$(".button a").click(function() {

    var $docWidth = $(window).width();
    var $boxOffset = $('#box1').offset();

    $("#box1").css('marginLeft', $boxOffset.left);
    $("#box1").animate({
        marginLeft: $docWidth
    }, 'slow');

});
```

CSS:

```
#container: { overflow: hidden; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dZUXJ/